# how to improve updating a large table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, informatica

I'm trying to improve performance on informatica presql command which updates a large table(100mil records) without a where clause (updates one column to null).
This takes me more then an hour and i have to get better results..
Any idea on how to improve it will be great..
Thanks in advance.
The table have 3 indexes and primary keys
Account
Subaccount
CaseId

Not partitioned.

For now its

```
 Update table1 set column1 = null
```

Comment: How can we optimize your code if we cannot see it?

Comment: Right now its only a normal update..

Comment: And the table structure? Indexes, foreign-key constraints, triggers, and so forth will greatly affect the performance of an update like this. We need to know if there are triggers, or any indexes or constraints on that column. If there are, it might be better to temporarily disable or remove them during the update.

Comment: There are no indexes or constraints on that column and the table doesbt have a trigger

Comment: Is anybody else writing to that table at the same time, blocking writing and causing retries? Only update what you need to update, `update table1 set column1 = null where column1 is not null`. Drop and add the column? Paralize the query, that may need a hint. Bigger Faster Better hardware.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable parallel dml  & hint to improve the performance.

```
alter session enable parallel dml;

UPDATE /*+ full(t) parallel (t 8) */ table1 t set column1 = null ;
```

You can view full article [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1077599?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

or you can try this, if u really dont need a WHERE:

```
alter table table1 drop column column1 ;

alter table table1 add column column1  column1_datatype default NUll ;
```

this will be fast :)

Comment: I thought about this but i cab change the structure and order of the table

Comment: you can delete, but you can't alter? a bit strange, but   then u should use parallel update at least

Comment: Can't* do both.. I'll try the parallel

Comment: why can't you alter? then how u develop? i dont understand, then you really need to ask the proper privs. You could use create table as select statement too

Comment: i think if u cannot alter and/or create table then you wont get better results, contact with your DBA

Comment: It's not rare for people to have DML rights but not DDL rights.

Comment: It's true but doesnt mean that is the right thing, because in cases like that u cannot do the proper/best solution and like we talking about nothing. There is a table with a 30 millions records, you cannot alter it, which means it's not your table, but you want to update it, the whole table. I think something it's not right about the (job)roles there or with the task

Comment: The problem is that if in the future we will need to add new columns it will change the order of the column which can causeva problem in informatica

Comment: I dont get it, the order of the columns doesnt matter, if there is a "insert into table2 select * from table1" statement, than it's a huge mistake

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964422/how-to-optimize-an-update-sql-that-runs-on-a-oracle-table-with-700m-rows

Answer (score 0):

you may also consider having a commit every 100,000 rows.

```
declare
  n_num number;
begin
  n_num := 0;
  for x in (select rowid rid from table1) loop
    Update table1 set column1 = null where rowid = x.rid;
    n_num := n_num + 1;
    if mod(n_num,100000) = 0 then
      commit;
    end if;
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
```